# Comparing model performance shows the Error in h(simpleError(msg, call))

Tags: r, regression, glmnet

I'm performing ridge and lasso regression for feature selection. My actual issue is related to the comparison between the two models, for example:

```
models <- list(ridge = ridge, lasso = lasso)
```

If I check the `models` output:

```
$ridge

Call:  cv.glmnet(x = x_train, y = y_train, type.measure = "mse", alpha = 0,      family = "binomial") 

Measure: Mean-Squared Error 

    Lambda Index Measure      SE Nonzero
min  3.518    51  0.2656 0.02807      86
1se  5.103    47  0.2916 0.02601      86

$lasso

Call:  cv.glmnet(x = x_train, y = y_train, type.measure = "mse", alpha = 1,      family = "binomial") 

Measure: Mean-Squared Error 

      Lambda Index Measure      SE Nonzero
min 0.003518    51 0.04640 0.02799      16
1se 0.020603    32 0.07214 0.03088      17
```

I know that the best model is the one that one that minimizes the prediction error, so I use the following line:

```
resamples(models) %>% 
  summary(metric = "RMSE")
```

That line must give me a summary and a comparison between the two models. However, I got the following error:

```
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'object' in selecting a method for function 'summary': values must be length 1,
 but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 0
```

So far I can not understand how to fix this.

This option only works with the test data or can I use the complete set too?

What could be the potential issue here? or explanation?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to get `caret::resamples` to work on outputs from `cv.glmnet`
I think you'd have to train your model in `caret` using `train` for it to work